# Issue with replacing the value of a parameter based on some condition

Tags: for

I am working on a script where I am passing a file as a argument to it.

The file has databases of two categories. One which starts with GDH_ and the others can be anything other than that. For ex:

```
GDH_Cust_spport
GDH_data_Staging
Emplyoyee_separation
General_Audit
Dataset
```

Here first 2 starts with GDH_ and the other fall in second category. Below is my current script:

```
./crab.sh -credfile  -a list -nof > $Import_List_File

  for DataBase in $(< "$1"); do  
  file_import=`grep -iw "CRQ_DI_PROD_$DataBase" "$Import_List_File" | grep -i prod`;   

     ##Testing if file_import variable has a value
     if [ -z "$file_import" ]; then
       echo "- $file_import file is not present . Please create " >> $Failure_Log
     else
       ## Importing the file 
       echo `date +'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'` "starting $file_import work" >> $Success_Log
       ./crab.sh -a start -i "$file_import"   >> Success_Log
       echo `date +'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'` "$file_import  completed" >> $Success_Log
```

All those which starts with GDH_ has to be appended with CRQ_DI_PROD and the value of file_import will be CRQ_DI_PROD_GDH_Cust_spport and CRQ_DI_PROD_GDH_data_Staging.

Now for the ones without GDH_ i want the file_import to contain the value without the GDH_ ones.

So far i have this approach and i have the file databases now in file_import_2 and file_import_3. How do i combine both of them now?

```
        ./crab.sh -credfile  -a list -t area -nof > List_File_test.txt


file_import_2=""
file_import_3=""
for DataBase in $(< "$1"); do

file_import_1=`grep -iw "CRQ_DI_PROD_$DataBase" "$Import_List_File" | grep -i prod`;
if [[ "$file_import_1" = GDH_* ]]; then
file_import_2=$file_import_1
echo $file_import_2
fi
if [[ "$import_area1" != GDH_* ]]; then
file_import_3=$DataBase
echo $file_import_3
fi

done
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where does `$import_area1` come from? And what shell are you using?

Comment: my bad ..edited.